# MVC Storefront - Kona - Where are they?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, storefront, mvc-storefront

I am looking for a full-blown shopping cart example for ASP.Net MVC. I found plenty of links pointing to MVC Storefront ([1](http://mvcsamples.codeplex.com/)) (Apparently not being developed anymore) and other articles which talk about Kona, a separate project based off MVC Storefront. Too bad, MVC Store Preview 1A had me pretty happy.

Are there any "production ready", open-source ASP.Net MVC Shopping Carts?

Answer (score 1):

The ASP.Net site has an example of a shopping cart, as part of a music store sample app: [link to shopping cart example](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions/mvc-music-store/mvc-music-store-part-8)