# Development on ASP.NET MVC Storefront Project

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, orchardcms, mvc-storefront

I see that there is no Check-Ins on [ASP.NET MVC Storefront code](http://github.com/robconery/Kona) since Feb 7th. Can anyone please make me aware about whats going on. And on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2114903/mvc-storefront-kona-where-are-they) question, Orchard project link is given with the answer. Is there any relation between these two projects?

Comment: I beg pardon that I've mistakenly downvoted @Daniel's answer instead of @Sohnee's answer. On @Sohnee's answer I've already given my explanation on why it should be downvoted (look at comment on that answer). Its clear that outdated and misleading information is given. I don't know what reason you have to call it a militancy. If you don't know the answer no one is forcing you to answer the question. Question will remain unanswered and whenever anyone will have info they will answer it. But whats the meaning of giving wrong info or one which is not asked in question?

Comment: Votes on answer is community's election of useful answer (check tooltip on votes to answer). So if you feel I've wrongly downvoted an answer, you can up vote it. Some other people will also do that and there will be no effect of my downvote then. If you didn't liked my comment, you can flag it offensive. Votes on question is community's election of usefulness and clearness of question (check tooltip on votes to question). @Igor, you should ask yourself that how much sound is the reason for which you have downvoted the question? In short don't take things personal.It's a community out here.

Comment: I represent the community just as much as the next person. I don't like the way you handled both answers to a question that is almost unanswerable by anyone but perhaps Rob Conery. I have the right to downvote the question as it represents your input into the community which, in this case, I consider negative. Nothing personal.

Comment: Can you let me know what is negative in my question? I would have taken back my wrong downvote on @Daniel's answer if I could. But it's locked now. If he edit's his answer, I will take it back.

Comment: See @Igor, now the problem with not actually answering and just providing info around on such question with bounty on it is that, tomorrow when the bounty will end, it will automatically tick an answer when I've not actually got a satisfactory answer from that. But if it remains unanswered, there will be still chances that someone else will give a definite answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The MVC Store Front project was written by Rob Conery and he blogs about it here:

http://blog.wekeroad.com/category/mvc-storefront

You'll note here that it was re-branded as "Kona", although some people referred to Kona as "MVC Store Front 2.0". After this, the sample application was moved on as part of an NHibernate screen cast...

http://tekpub.com/preview/nhibernate

And some sources say that the Orchard Project assimilated the MVC Store Front sample as a component of a much larger content management system, which as you know is located here...

http://www.orchardproject.net/

http://orchard.codeplex.com/

Although I can't find any documentation on the Orchard Project website that confirms that it contains the MVC Store Front or a derivative thereof.

The main reason for losing the trail on this project is that Rob Conery left Microsoft while making the original MVC Store Front screen casts, so this is where the historical black-spot come from in this series.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure what the status of MVC Storefront is, but I can tell you that it is unrelated to the Orchard project. Orchard is more of a Content Management System that has been developed by a group of Microsoft ASP.NET developers. It is currently actively developed.  Kona is described by its author as "My little commerce app" on [this page](http://github.com/robconery/Kona). I have had no response from my emails to the author, so I guess it is currently shelved.

Comment: Thanks @Daniel.
Actulally, I was looking for some sure answers. I could have also guessed as there are no check in since Feb first week.